# Database design for filtering places by geolocation

Tags: sql, search, database-design, geolocation, database-schema

I have 2 entities in my `PostgreSQL`:

```
@Entity()
export class Listing extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
  title: string // For example, 'Best restaurant for work and english learning'

  @Column({ type: 'double precision', nullable: true })
  latitude: number // For example: 41.87194

  @Column({ type: 'double precision', nullable: true })
  longitude: number // For example: 12.56738

  // Solution 1
  // @ManyToMany(() => City, city => city.listing) 
  // city: City

  @OneToMany(() => Offer, offer => offer.listing)
  offerList: Offer[]
}

@Entity()
export class Offer extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number

  @Column({ type:'text' })
  position: string // For example: 'cashier'

  @Column({ type:'int' })
  wage: number // For example: 6

  @ManyToOne(() => Listing, listing => listing.offerList)
  listing: Listing
}
```

**What is the best way to filtering `listings(places)` by `city/county` if I 100% store `latitude` and `longitude`?**

*Search request example: `waiter offers in Italy`*

**Solution1**: store in `Listing entity` additional fields, like `city` (and `country`?). 
(Actualy, it will be separate many-to-many(city <= => listing) entity to avoid user chaos, optimize `SQL` searching requests and easily add new city into `production database`, am I right?)

**Solution2**: when user typed `Italy`, client send this query to backend. After that backend parse and fetch `longitude` and `latitude` for `Italy` query(I assume some bugs will be there, like `strange query`). Then backend starts to search listings(places), which located near to received geolocation. The closer the better search rank

**Solution3**: your solution... =)

Here is how airbnb search engine works, they don't have list of hardcode cities

[image: airbnb solution]

Comment: With postgresql you could use postgis and the related  topological function  .. (using proper geometrics or geographics ) otherwise  the relation between city and lat/long could be based easly on a bounding box

Comment: googled `postgis`, wow, its awesome, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try https://postgis.net

It adds support for geographic objects allowing location queries to be run in SQL.

```
SELECT superhero.name
FROM city, superhero
WHERE ST_Contains(city.geom, superhero.geom)
AND city.name = 'Gotham';
```